# Can I access a Spreadsheet by Title in Google Sheets api v4 using the PHP client (or at all!)?

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

We used to access Google spreadsheets like this via php:-

```
$spreadsheetService = new SpreadsheetService();
$spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();
$spreadsheet = $spreadsheetFeed->getByTitle($spreadsheetTitle);
```

However I cannot see any examples of doing this via the v4 api. Has this getByTitle functionality been removed?

It looks to me like it has. However I thought as a workaround there may be some way of getting a list of the available spreadsheets for the authenticated Google_Client which would list the spreadsheetId and the Title - which would allow me to programmatically update our existing code to the new api by grabbing the id in this manner - but I can't find anything like that either.

Has anyone encountered this issue and found a solution?

---

**Here's a workable solution for anyone else encountering this problem** (potentially when also migrating to v4):-

```
....

$this->spreadsheetService = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
$googleDrive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$spreadsheetId = "";

$parameters = [];
//$parameters['q'] = urlencode("mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'");

$googleDriveFiles = $googleDrive->files->listFiles($parameters);
$files = $googleDriveFiles['files'];

foreach($files as $file){
   if ($file['name'] === $spreadsheetTitle){
       $spreadsheetId = $file['id'];
       break;
   }
}

$range = $worksheetTitle;
$worksheet = $this->spreadsheetService->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
...
```

You'll notice the commented out mimeType parameter setting. Unfortunately although I could add that mimeType in against the "q" parameter in the Google console, I couldn't get it to work via the php wrapper. If anyone has worked out how to do that please let me know and I'll update this solution...

Comment: Reference: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php

Comment: That's no good, i.e. $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range) I wish to access via Title not spreadsheetId

Comment: Yes, but it is a Google_Service_Sheets object and not SpreadsheetService

Comment: I don't understand why you referenced that then? As per the Question if there is a way to grab the spreadsheetId at a higher level that'd be fine but I'm not too sure why you referenced that example which requires knowing the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Drive.Files.list with a query parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22q%22%3A%22name%20%3D%20%27hello%27%22%7D) then use the IDs returned
on [Spreadsheets.get to "open" your spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get?apix_params=%7B%22spreadsheetId%22%3A%22Your-Sheet-ID%22%7D).

To learn more about the `q` parameter, read [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files).

For filtering by MimeType as well as by title, you can do `name = 'yourname' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'`, for example.

Comment: Thanks that was indeed the way. Please have a look at my update above - if you do know how that q parameter should be set for the mimeType that would be useful in reducing the array set to loop through. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, that documentation link is useful (and where I was looking) but as you'll see there's no php example. I commented out the parameter setting line I thought should work in my solution above. I can get a result using mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' in the console, it's just the php code for the q parameter which I was having problems with.